# How can i allow only positive number in my code

Tags: vb.net

I'm still new in VB and I have emailed my lecturer but it seems like he is quite busy and didn't have time to reply to me. Can anyone teach me with it?

```
Dim split = InputTextBox.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
Dim check As Boolean

For i = 0 To split.Length - 1
  check = IsNumeric(split(i))
  If Not check Then
    Exit For
  End If
Next

If check Then
  FootForm.Show()
Else
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter in positive number only")
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throw a bit of LINQ at the problem:

```
If InputTextBox.Lines.All(Function(s)
                              Dim n As Double

                              Return Double.TryParse(s, n) AndAlso n >= 0.0
                          End Function) Then
    'All lines represent non-negative numbers.
End If
```

The longhand version would be:

```
Dim result = True

For Each s In InputTextBox.Lines
    Dim n As Double

    If Not Double.TryParse(s, n) OrElse n < 0.0 Then
        result = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If result Then
    'All lines represent non-negative numbers.
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your value is stored in the form control.  The  below should help

```
        Dim split as String = InputTextBox.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
        Dim parsedint as Integer

        If Int32.TryParse(split, parsedint) AndAlso parsedint < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter in positive number only")
        Else
            FootForm.Show()
        End If
```

Comment: Your `If` statement is correct but your use of `Split` is wrong.  It propagates an error from the original code and adds more besides.  There's no need for `Split` here at all, given that the `TextBox` already has a `Lines` property.

Comment: I just used the Split from your code.  You can remove if it is not required.